# Merging different dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

This is a long question so please bear with me. I start out with 3 dicts obtained from 3 APIs. the dicts have a structure like so:

```
API1 = {'results':[{'url':'www.site.com','title':'A great site','snippet':'This is a great site'},
{'url':'www.othersite.com','title':'Another site','snippet':'This is another site'},
{'url':'www.wiki.com','title':'A wiki site','snippet':'This is a wiki site'}]}

API2 = {'hits':[{'url':'www.dol.com','title':'The DOL site','snippet':'This is the dol site'},
{'url':'www.othersite.com','title':'Another site','snippet':'This is another site'},
{'url':'www.whatever.com','title':'Whatever site','snippet':'This is a site about whatever'}]}

API3 = {'output':[{'url':'www.dol.com','title':'The DOL site','snippet':'This is the dol site'},
{'url':'www.whatever.com','title':'Whatever site','snippet':'This is a site about whatever'},
{'url':'www.wiki.com','title':'A wiki site','snippet':'This is a wiki site'}]}
```

I extract the URL keys from API1, API2 and API3 to do some processing. I do this because there is quite a bit of processing to be done and only the URLs are needed. When finished I have a list of the URL's with the duplicates removed and another list of scores that are relative to each URL's position in the list:

```
URLlist = ['www.site.com','www.wiki.com','www.othersite.com','www.dol.com','www.whatever.com']

Results = [1.2, 6.5, 3.5, 2.1, 4.0]
```

What I have done is created a new dictionary from these 2 lists using the `zip()` function.

`ScoredResults = dict(zip(URLlist,Results))`

```
{'www.site.com':1.2,'www.wiki.com':6.5, 'www.othersite.com':3.5, 'www.dol.com':2.1, 'www.whatever.com':4.0}
```

Now what I need to do is to link the URL's from `ScoredResults` with `API1`,`API2` or `API3` so that I have a new dictionary like so:

```
Full Results = 
{'www.site.com':{'title':'A great site','snippet':'This is a great site','score':1.2},
 'www.othersite.com':{'title':'Another site','snippet':'This is another site','score':3.5},
...}
```

This is too difficult for me to do. If you look back on my question history I have been asking numerous dictionary questions but no implementation has worked so far. If anyone could please point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Can you be guaranteed that the results returned in your various APIs are unique?  For example, you have `www.dol.com` as a url in both API2 and API3.  Is this actually possible in your real code?  If so, just given URL, it's impossible to tell whether it came from API2 or API3.

Comment: @mgilson yes duplications are possible in the URL's but I would be happy with any version of the title/snippet so something like `if url1 in API1 get title and snippet, elif in API2 get title and snippet...`

Comment: Are the dictionaries returned by the various API's really that simple?  (i.e., do they always have only 1 key/value pair?)

Comment: @mgilson there are other keys but they are not relevant for what I need. I've only shown the parts I need. If I could attach a file I could send you the whole output of one API that you could see for yourself. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick attempt:

```
from itertools import chain

full_result = {}

for blah in chain.from_iterable(d.itervalues() for d in (API1, API2, API3)):
    for d in blah:
        full_result[d['url']] = {
            'title': d['title'],
            'snippet': d['snippet'],
            'score': ScoredResults[d['url']]
        }

print full_result
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've been experimenting somewhat with `itertools` and this is a good use of it. Will keep this method to hand!

Answer (score 1):

With the given data…

```
Full_Results = {d['url']: {'title': d['title'], 'snippet': d['snippet'], 'score': ScoredResults[d['url']]} for d in API1['results']+API2['hits']+API3['output']}
```

resulting into:

```
{'www.dol.com': {'score': 2.1,
  'snippet': 'This is the dol site',
  'title': 'The DOL site'},
 'www.othersite.com': {'score': 3.5,
  'snippet': 'This is another site',
  'title': 'Another site'},
 'www.site.com': {'score': 1.2,
  'snippet': 'This is a great site',
  'title': 'A great site'},
 'www.whatever.com': {'score': 4.0,
  'snippet': 'This is a site about whatever',
  'title': 'Whatever site'},
 'www.wiki.com': {'score': 6.5,
  'snippet': 'This is a wiki site',
  'title': 'A wiki site'}}
```

Comment: what if `snippet` was called `excerpt` in `API2` for example? Just for the sake of clarity, is the structure still the same?

Comment: @adohertyd - then it becomes more complicated and you would have to define mapping dicts pointing to possible names.

Comment: 2/3 of the API's have the same keys but one has 'Url' instead of 'url' as a key and 'excerpt' instead of 'snippet'. Would the best course of action here be to create a new dict from the odd one assigning the key values that I want? Followed by implementing your code

Comment: @adohertyd - it wouldn't be a one-liner then, so you can take the code of JonClements (now functionally almost identical to mine) and add these mappings.

Answer (score 1):

I would transform the API's into something that is more meaningful for you.  A dict of urls is probably more appropriate:

```
def transform_API(API):
    list_of_dict=API.get('results',API.get('hits',API.get('output')))
    if(list_of_dict is None):
       raise KeyError("results, hits or output not in API")
    d={}
    for dct in list_of_dict:
        d[dct['url']]=dct
        dct.pop('url')
    return d

API1=transform_API(API1)
API2=transform_API(API2)
API3=transform_API(API3)

master={}
for d in (API1,API2,API3):
    master.update(d)

urls=list(master.keys())
scores=get_scores_from_urls(urls)

for k,score in zip(urls,scores):
    master[k]['score']=score
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it doesn't solve my problem of getting the titles and snippets into a new dictionary?

Comment: @adohertyd -- the titles, snippets, and everything else that was in the original dictionaries should be in master along with scores.  `master[url]['title']` or `master[url]['snippet']`

Comment: Ah yes I see now sorry I think I'm blinded by frustration at this stage! thank you

Comment: @adohertyd -- No problem.  Hopefully this is useful and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Would something like that work for you ? It's rather basic, constructing your final dictionary by looping on `URLlist`.

```
API1r = API1['results']
API2r = API2['hits']
API3r = API3['output']

FullResults = {}
for (U, R) in zip(URLlist, Results):
    FullResults[U] = {}
    for api in (API1r, API2r, API3r):
        for v in api:
            k = dict()
            k.update(v)
            if (k.pop('url') == U):
                FullResults[U].update((k.items()+[('score', R)]))
```

Note that as the same `url` may be present in your different `API`s but with different information, we need to create the corresponding entry in `FullResults` beforehand, so it might be a bit tricky to simplify the loops.
LMKHIW.

Comment: yes that will be an issue so it isn't going to be as simple as that. I have quite a bit to go on here however so I'm sure I can make it work

Comment: well, if you can have either `"url"` or `"Url"`, you can modify the loop accordingly. Note that not assuming specific keys for each item of the `API`s make this solution a tad more adaptable than the more elegant ones which were already posted.